# Is there a way to label my map markers with letters?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

```
function initialize() {
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};

// Display a map on the page
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
map.setTilt(45);

// Multiple Markers

var markers = [
    ['Joe Brown Park, New Orleans',             30.030342, -89.966561],
    ['City Park, New Orleans',                  29.993514, -90.098118]
];

// Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent = [

    [
    '<h3>Joe Brown Park</h3>' +
    '<h3>Named after 1 of the states largest independent oil producers, this park offers year-round events.</h3>' +
    '</div>'],
    [
    '<h3>City Park </h3>' +
    '<h3>A 1,300 acre public park in New Orleans, Louisiana, is the 87th largest and 7th-most-visited urban public park in the United States.</h3>' +
    '</div>'],
];

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(
        markers[i][1], 
        markers[i][2],
        markers[i][3]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

}
```

Can I just add an Icon variable to my working map or something simple or do I need to change most of my code to add letters to my markers? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another column in markers array:

```
var markers = [
    ['Joe Brown Park, New Orleans',             30.030342, -89.966561,'','PATHTOICON/icon1.png'],
    ['City Park, New Orleans',                  29.993514, -90.098118,'','PATHTOICON/icon2.jpg']
];
```

And then at the loop that is adding the markers just add icon: and point to the icon column in the array

```
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(
        markers[i][1], 
        markers[i][2],
        markers[i][3]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0],
        icon: markers[i][4]// <=== each marker can have its own icon
    });
```

Comment: Why have you taken the answer down?

Comment: Not sure how that happened. Sorry @binaryghost

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 supports [single character labels on markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels), this will label your marker with the number (zero based) of the marker in your array.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: map,
  title: markers[i][0],
  label: ""+i
});
```

If you want it to be a letter, you can either add the letter to the array as a fourth element or convert the array index into a letter:

```
var label = String.fromCharCode(65+i);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: map,
  title: markers[i][0],
  label: label
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/n02m18uc/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  };

  // Display a map on the page
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  map.setTilt(45);

  // Multiple Markers
  var markers = [
    ['Joe Brown Park, New Orleans', 30.030342, -89.966561],
    ['City Park, New Orleans', 29.993514, -90.098118]
  ];

  // Info Window Content
  var infoWindowContent = [
    [
      '<h3>Joe Brown Park</h3>' +
      'Named after 1 of the states largest independent oil producers, this park offers year-round events.' +
      '</div>'
    ],
    [
      '<h3>City Park </h3>' +
      'A 1,300 acre public park in New Orleans, Louisiana, is the 87th largest and 7th-most-visited urban public park in the United States.' +
      '</div>'
    ],
  ];

  // Display multiple markers on a map
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
  // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(
      markers[i][1],
      markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    var label = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i][0],
      label: label
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that informational link and the quick response.